# Sharepoint Search API : Merge PrimaryQueryResult and SecondaryQueryResults

Tags: search-results

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='data'&sourceid=\'b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31\'&RowLimit=10&startrow=0
```

I am getting results, but am getting confuse on `PrimaryQueryResults` and `SecondaryQueryResuls`. I had set Row Limit as 10 but am getting 4 rows in `PrimaryQueryResults` and 8 in `SecondaryQueryResult`. 
So, total Primary and Secondary Results is 12.

Comment: ^^^what does this mean, not very helpful sorry to say. I'm running into the same problem. If I do a search I get less results than I expect in primary, but more than whats missing in secondary. If I search for the exact same thing but add * to the end, I get them all in the primary result set

Answer (score 0):

A `QueryResult` structure accessed by the `PrimaryQueryResult` property of a SearchResult structure **MUST NOT be associated with a query rule**, and MUST have the QueryRuleId populated with the value {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.

Each `QueryResult` structure contained in the `SecondaryQueryResults` of the SearchResult structure **MUST be associated with an individual query rule**, and MUST have the QueryRuleId populated with a value other than {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}.

[Reference take from MSDN article on CSOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh661326(v=office.12).aspx).